# Soft keyboard not showing up in my Air application running on Windows 8 (Surface Pro)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, keyboard, windows-8.1

I have an Adobe Air app that has some text fields that need input. When I run this app on Windows 8, giving focus to the text fields correctly displays the cursor in the field (and if you use the attached hardware keyboard or a bluetooth keyboard you can type into the fields) however the device's soft keyboard does NOT come up within the app (even though it does come up when I focus into a text field in a regular web form or browser address bar).  I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm overlooking something that I must manually do in AS3 to provoke the device's soft keyboard to show up when the text field takes focus.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of AIR (13 was released yesterday, 4.0 released ~2 months ago)? Are you using `StageText`? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem for my app for android and ios.

My solution was to use the Textinput component in Flash Pro and export it in my swc file. Works like you'd expect. Softkeyboard shows up in android and ios.

Comment: thanks, I'm no longer working on this problem, but if I come back to it, I'll attempt your solution.